# Cannot read key from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

So basically I have an activity (`SplashActivity`) that serves as a splash screen. It reads a key named `username` from the application's `SharedPreferences`, then if it finds the key, starts `HomePage` activity. Otherwise it starts `LoginActivity`. When the login is successful in `LoginActivity`, I am storing the username and password via this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = LoginActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.apply();
```

The login page also has an autocomplete feature for the password field. This is how I am reading the password:

```
String password = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("password", "");
```

And I get the stored password. However, when I restart the app and run `SplashActivity` I can't read the password despite using the exact same code as above. Is there something wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the JavaDocs for `getPreferences()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity#getpreferences):

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences **that are private to this activity**.

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

So, `SplashActivity` cannot read a value written to the private preferences of `LoginActivity`.

You probably want to switch to [`getSharedPreferences()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getSharedPreferences(kotlin.String,%20kotlin.Int)), where you provide your own name that can be shared between the two activities.

Comment: @WaisKamal: You're welcome! And the Kotlin docs are a bit more future-proof (I still call them JavaDocs because, technically, they *are* JavaDocs in the implementation).